# iText extract faulty locations of text chunks

Tags: java, algorithm, pdf, itext

I am developing an algorithm to extract text and images from PDF files in the reading order. I use iText java for this purpose and basically my algorithm works as follows.

1. Coordinates of every text chunk in the page is extracted using iText.
2. Rectangle object is created using the extracted coordinates. After this    step we have whole bunch of rectangle objects representing actual text chunks in the page.
3. Group the rectangles into larger text blocks which will be corresponding to the actual columns in the pdf page.
4. Order the text blocks by Y then X
5. Apply the `locationTextExtractionStrategy` for text blocks one by one.

This approach gives my around 80% or slightly more results for the PDF files with medium to complex layouts. I know that it will be almost impossible to gain 100% accuracy because PDF files does not store information in the reading order.

What I want to do is to increase my accuracy here but the problem is iText stops me from doing that. I have identified a problem in iText. It sometimes extract false locations of text chunks which makes my algorithm incorrect. Following images are a good example for that.

[image: Actual Pdf Page]
[image: Resulting Rectangles after extraction using iText]

You can see that in the actual PDF page there is a clear gap between columns. But the resulting rectangles contains some faulty rectangles in between that gap which prevents me from identifying the correct columns.

Following is the code that I use to extract locations of text chunks.

```
package com.InteliText.Extract;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.ImageRenderInfo;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.LineSegment;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.TextExtractionStrategy;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.TextRenderInfo;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.Vector;

/*
 * THIS CLASS ACT AS THE TEXT EXTRACTOR FOR THE PREPROCESSOR 
 */
public class PreProcessorStrategy extends SimpleTextExtractionStrategy{

    private StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    private ArrayList<Double> fontSizes = new ArrayList<Double>();
    private ArrayList<Double> lineSpaces = new ArrayList<Double>();
    private ArrayList<TextSegment> textSegments = new ArrayList<TextSegment>();

    Vector previousBaseLine = null;

    @Override
    public void beginTextBlock() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void endTextBlock() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void renderImage(ImageRenderInfo arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) {

        //This code assumes that if the baseline changes then we're on a newline
        Vector curBaseline = renderInfo.getBaseline().getStartPoint();
        Vector topRight = renderInfo.getAscentLine().getEndPoint();
        //System.out.println(renderInfo.getText()+"\t"+curBaseline.get(0)+"\t"+topRight.get(0));

        if(curBaseline.get(1) < 800 && curBaseline.get(1) > 50 ) {
            // Chunk of text as a rectangle
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(curBaseline.get(0), curBaseline.get(1), topRight.get(0), topRight.get(1));

            double curFontSize = rect.getHeight();
            fontSizes.add(curFontSize);
            String text = renderInfo.getText();
            boolean isBullet = text.contains("•");
            if(!(text.equals(" ") || text.equals("  ") || text.equals("   ")) && !isBullet) {
                double endX = topRight.get(0);
                if(text.endsWith(" "))
                    endX -= 8;

                textSegments.add(new TextSegment(curBaseline.get(0),endX,curBaseline.get(1),topRight.get(1),renderInfo.getText(),curFontSize));
            }

            result.append(renderInfo.getText());
        }
        previousBaseLine = topRight;
    }

    @Override
    public String getResultantText() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.toString();
    }

    public ArrayList<TextSegment> getResultantTextSegments() {
        return this.textSegments;
    }
```

I use the resulting `textSegments` ArrayList to create rectangle objects by looking at the coordinates stored in those textSegments. I suspects that this is might be a bug in iText.

As you can see currently I'm shrinking the text chunks a little bit if the content of that text chunk ends with a white space. But this is a temporary fix and I don't want to do that because it shrink the correct text chunks too.

So is there a work around for this one? Or if it is a problem in my code please help me to fix that..

Comment: It looks like the text showing operations show a trailing space which is part of your box and goes beyond the column border.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming here that if you knew where the columns were you could assign each rectangle to the correct column. It looks to me that if you drew a line down the left edge of the right hand column you could assign almost all of the rectangles correctly based on whether their centre was to the right or left of that edge. So the problem is to find the parameters that describe the data best (in particular the left hand edge of the rightmost column) in the presence of outliers.

The absolutely correct way is probably to fit some sort of statistical model, but I think there are a couple of easier hacks that might work.

1) All of the overlapping rectangles in your image seem to be very small. Perhaps you can simply remove rectangles below a given size, work out where the columns should be, and then assign each small rectangle according to whether its centre is to the left or right of the left hand edge of the right hand column.

2) There is a general strategy for fitting data contaminated by outliers you can derive from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC.

2a) Start by fitting the model to only a small amount of the data. You will be repeating 2a and 2b multiple times, and picking the best result. You are hoping that the initial points chosen for one of these cases are completely free of outliers. Note that if there are N outliers and you divide the data into N+1 chunks, at least one of these chunks must be completely free of outliers.

2b) Once you have an initial fit, look at all the data and work out which points are outliers and ignore them temporarily (i.e. put aside the k worst fitting points). Then fit the model again using the remaining points. In many cases you can prove that if you repeat this step indefinitely it will eventually converge to something, because changing the points identified as the k worst fits improves the fit, as does re-fitting the model, so each iteration improves the fit until you there is no change, at which point you declare that the process has converged.

Comment: Thank you very much for those suggestions. Your first suggestion will not work because in some pdf files almost all the rectangles are pretty small. Because iText extract only one letter per text chunk sometimes. So If I ignore smaller boxes, then I might miss whole bunch of required rectangles too..
Moving onto your second suggestion, Your answer might work for the provided example above. But I have seen so many pdf pages which almost all the text lines intercepting other columns. In those cases It seems to me that, neglecting outliers will not give a better result... What do you think?

Comment: The correct way to do this is almost certainly to create a statistical model for how the rectangles are generated and where they end up, and then fit this model to the available data. To test this sort of thing out and develop the model you will need a collection of test data, especially if some pages - like the one that you provided with the question - are not representative of most of what happens in real life. Or use machine learning. Pick out which features of pages and rectangles are important (this is the hard part) and then use e.g. Weka to try a variety of machine learning schemes.